# Only to compile java file and save the class file to other directory

Tags: eclipse

I've got following scenario:

I wrote a Java class in Eclipse. After that I executed it. For example -a simple addition program.

The first Java file will be compiled and the generated class file is stored into the bin folder and then class file will be executed. So far so good.

My requirement is, I don't want to run the generated class file. Instead of execution, I only want to copy the class file into a different folder automatically. Is it possible in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, you want to look at ant to just build and the copy your file to another directory.

Comment: @david99world or Maven or an alternative build framework

Comment: True, but Maven has a lot more functionality (not that it can't be used just for what OP requires) where as a simple ant script seemed the most direct.  I did not intend to imply ant was the only build framework.

Comment: If you just want to store the .class file in another directory than bin you can modify this from project properties->java build path->default output folder.